# Bash does not allow if statement inside case statement

Tags: bash

Can someone help me find out what I am doing wrong on this bash script. I am trying to using if statement inside case statement and bash is complaining syntax error.

```
findinfo() {
OPT1=$1
case  "$OPT1" in
   linux)
        echo "Setting environment"
        ESC="hello_linux" if [[ "$PROJN" == "ONE" ||  "$PROJN" == "two" ]]
        ;;
   Windows)
        echo "Setting environment"
        ESC="hello_windows" if [[ "$PROJN" == "ONE" ||  "$PROJN" == "two" ]]
        ;;
   Android)
        echo "Setting environment"
        ESC="hello_android" if [[ "$PROJN" == "ONE" ||  "$PROJN" == "two" ]]
        ;;
esac

}
```

Thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `case`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In bash, `if` must precede the `then` part:

```
if [[ "$PROJN" == "ONE" ||  "$PROJN" == "two" ]] ; then ESC=hello_linux ; fi
```

The "postfix" `if` is possible in Perl (and maybe somewhere else, too), but not in bash.

Comment: Needs to be `ESC=hello_linux`, not `ESC = hello_linux`; the whitespace makes this a command `ESC` with two arguments, `=` and `hello_linux`.

Answer (score 8):

The following syntax is a terser alternative:

```
[[ $PROJN = ONE || $PROJN = TWO ]] && ESC=hello_linux
```

...and the following is still shorter, and compliant with older shells:

```
case $PROJN in ONE|TWO) ESC=hello_linux ;; esac
```

Comment: @devnull No, I really don't. Better to quote when it isn't needed than not to quote when it _is_ needed, though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem using an `if` inside a case statement. It's that your `if` statements are a wee bit incorrect.

You had your `if` statement on the same line as your `$ESC` assignment. Doesn't work outside of a `case` doesn't work inside. Also, you need to use `-o` for the *or* in your `if` statements, and you need AT LEAST one line to execute if your `if` statement is true. (I just put an `echo` as a place holder).

It could be that this particular `if` statement should be outside of your `case`. I notice that they're all the same. No need to duplicate code in that case, just put your `if` after the `esac`.

By the way: You can do an `or` inside of an if in either one of these two ways:

```
if [[ "$PROJN" == "ONE" -o  "$PROJN" == "two" ]]
```

or

```
if [[ "$PROJN" == "ONE" ]] || [[  "$PROJN" == "two" ]]
```

And now back your regularly scheduled program...

```
findinfo() {
    OPT1=$1
    case  "$OPT1" in
       linux)
            echo "Setting environment"
            ESC="hello_linux" 
            if [[ "$PROJN" == "ONE" -o  "$PROJN" == "two" ]]
            then
                 echo "Here be dragons..."
            fi
            ;;
       Windows)
            echo "Setting environment"
            ESC="hello_windows" 
            if [[ "$PROJN" == "ONE" -o  "$PROJN" == "two" ]]
            then
                 echo "Here be dragons..."
            fi
            ;;
       Android)
            echo "Setting environment"
            ESC="hello_android" 
            if [[ "$PROJN" == "ONE" -o "$PROJN" == "two" ]]
            then
                 echo "Here be dragons..."
            fi
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: Use of `-o` inside of `[[ ]]` is wrong; it should be the `||` operator.

Comment: To expand on Charles' comment, `-o` is also deprecated inside `[ ]`. In that case, you would use `[ ] || [ ]` instead (two separate `test` commands).

Comment: `[[ '' -o true ]]` is not "one of two ways", it's just (in bash) outright broken / entirely unsupported (at least in bash 3.2.57, as shipped by Apple; I haven't tested with all other extant releases).  Try it: ``-bash: syntax error near `-o'``. Which shell were you testing with which didn't throw such an error?